# Merge multidimensional array (recursive) but skip duplicate values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, array-merge

I have two multidimensional arrays what I want to merge but, I want to skip the same values during merging. I tried several different ways what I find on the web, but nothing help me in my case.

My initial array is much bigger than this one, but here I just put an example:

```
$array1 = [
    "aaa" => [
        "aa1"=> [
            "key1"=> "value1",
            "key2"=> "value2",
        ],
        "bbb"=> [
            "bb1",
            "bb2",
        ],
        "ccc"=> [
            "cc1",
        ],
    ],
    "ooo" => [
        "oo1"
    ]
];
```

And another one, which I want to merge in the first one:

```
$array2 = [
    "aaa" => [
        "bbb"=> [
            "bb2",
        ],
        "ccc"=> [
            "cc2",
        ],
    ],
];
```

print_r of the array_merge_recurisive, using the method like:
`print_r(array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2));`

```
Array
(
    [aaa] => Array
        (
            [aa1] => Array
                (
                    [key1] => value1
                    [key2] => value2
                )

            [bbb] => Array
                (
                    [0] => bb1
                    [1] => bb2
                    [2] => bb2
                )

            [ccc] => Array
                (
                    [0] => cc1
                    [1] => cc2
                )

        )

    [ooo] => Array
        (
            [0] => oo1
        )

)
```

So, in the result as you can see array `bbb` have two `bb2` values, but I need just one

Comment: have you tried $arr = `array_unique (array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2));`

Comment: check this: [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php). notice the line: *If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.*

Comment: @lovelace yes, I tried, but not help in my case.

Answer (score 4):

The following function will remove duplicate values for an array recursively (edit: **only for non-associative keys**):

```
function array_unique_recursive(array $arr) {
  if (array_keys($arr) === range(0, count($arr) - 1)) {
    $arr = array_unique($arr, SORT_REGULAR);
  }

  foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {
    if (is_array($item)) {
      $arr[$key] = array_unique_recursive($item);
    }
  }

  return $arr;
}
```

You can call it after `array_merge_recursive`.

Comment: Yes, it is one of the solutions. I tried to do it in one step.

Comment: @Kolesar, define what you mean with "one step". Also, since this is a solution, it is acceptable. You seem to suggest you already know several solutions. In that case your question is off-topic for StackOverflow. You may want to look at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and see if your question would be on-topic there.

Comment: I tried now this method, and it does not work in case if we have some like: "bbb"=> [
            "bb1",
            "bb2",
        ],
        "ccc"=> [
            "bb1",
            "bb2",
        ],

ccc will be removed in this case, because have "same array content"

Comment: @Kolesar Edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

Use `array_replace_recursive` instead of `array_merge_recursive`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

array_unique(array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR);

Comment: Please add an explanation on how this solves OP's issue.

Comment: If you try with arrays from the first post, you will see that this not work, too.