# Combining two or more arrays into one array according to numeric keys without duplicates in subarrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, array-merge

I have the following scenario made of arrays with numeric keys.
I need to have an array which stores all the values in the arrays grouped by numeric key and without duplicates.
I cannot make them strings as they are IDs and need to stay numeric.

Starting point:

```
    Array
    (
        [77] => Array
            (
                [0] => Bold Condensed
                [1] => Bold Condensed 2
                [2] => Bold Condensed 3
            )
    
    )
    Array
    (
        [77] => Array
            (
                [0] => Bold Condensed
            )
    
        [136] => Array
            (
                [0] => Regular
            )
    
    )
    Array
    (
        [77] => Array
            (
                [0] => Bold Condensed (1, 2, 3)
            )
    
        [168] => Array
            (
                [0] => Regular
                [1] => Bold
            )
    
    )
```

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [77] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bold Condensed
            [1] => Bold Condensed 2
            [2] => Bold Condensed 3
            [3] => Bold Condensed (1 ,2 ,3)
        )

    [136] => Array
        (
            [0] => Regular
        )

    [168] => Array
        (
            [0] => Regular
            [1] => Bold
        )

)
```

Tried array_merge and array_merge_recursive:

```
$megaArray = [];

foreach( $arrays as $key => $value) {
  if(array_key_exists($key, $arrays)){
    $megaArray[$key] = array_merge_recursive($value);
  }
}
```

What I'm getting with both array_merge and array_merge_recursive:

```
Array
(
    [77] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bold Condensed (1, 2, 3)
        )

    [136] => Array
        (
            [0] => Regular
        )

    [168] => Array
        (
            [0] => Regular
            [1] => Bold
        )

)
```

Both `array_merge()` and `array_merge_recursive()` seem to store the latest value for each key.

Comment: This condition: `array_key_exists($key, $arrays)` will always be true inside your `foreach` loop, becuase `$arrays` is what you are iterating over.  Also, since you are only supplying one array to `array_merge_recursive`, it is just returning it, rather than merging it with anything

Comment: @ilariaroglieri Your question and code above has a contradiction built in: you first talk of arrays, and also the starting code shows three separate arrays. But then your foreach clause loops over a structure $array*s*, which seems to consists of the data of the three arrays. What is it? The three arrays, or one array with the three arrays nested?

Comment: Related: [PHP - Merging two arrays into one array (also Remove Duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13469803/2943403) and [Merge two 2d arrays and remove duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58340464/2943403) and [Merge two arrays containing objects and remove duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10572546/2943403) and [Combine two 2d arrays and have duplicate rows removed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12538327/2943403) and for non-numeric keyed arrays: [Merge multidimensional array (recursive) but skip duplicate values in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52774268/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need a combination of `array_merge` and `array_unique` (since I note you don't have duplicates in your leaf arrays):

```
$megaArray = [];

foreach ($arrays as $subArray) {
  foreach ($subArray as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $megaArray)) {
      $megaArray[$key] = array_unique(array_merge($megaArray[$key], $value));
    } else {
      $megaArray[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected output, it seems you need to check key and values at the same time. I write a code that create exact output array like your sample. No need to say that you can use function to simplify the whole process but for understanding the principle of situation, I repeat foreach each time.

```
$newarray = array();

//-------------
$array1 = array();
$array1[77][0] = 'Bold Condensed';
$array1[77][1] = 'Bold Condensed 2';
$array1[77][2] = 'Bold Condensed 3';

foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $newarray)) {
        foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
            if (!array_key_exists($subkey, $newarray[$key])) {
                $newarray[$key][$subkey] = $subvalue;
            } elseif (array_key_exists($subkey, $newarray[$key]) and $subvalue != $newarray[$key][$subkey]) {
                $newkey = count($newarray[$key]);
                $newarray[$key][$newkey] = $subvalue;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $newarray[$key] = $value;
    }
}

//-------------
$array2 = array();
$array2[77][0] = 'Bold Condensed';
$array2[136][0] = 'Regular';

foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $newarray)) {
        foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
            if (!array_key_exists($subkey, $newarray[$key])) {
                $newarray[$key][$subkey] = $subvalue;
            } elseif (array_key_exists($subkey, $newarray[$key]) and $subvalue != $newarray[$key][$subkey]) {
                $newkey = count($newarray[$key]);
                $newarray[$key][$newkey] = $subvalue;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $newarray[$key] = $value;
    }
}

//-------------
$array3 = array();
$array3[77][0] = 'Bold Condensed (1, 2, 3)';
$array3[168][0] = 'Regular';
$array3[168][1] = 'Bold';

foreach($array3 as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $newarray)) {
        foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
            if (!array_key_exists($subkey, $newarray[$key])) {
                $newarray[$key][$subkey] = $subvalue;
            } elseif (array_key_exists($subkey, $newarray[$key]) and $subvalue != $newarray[$key][$subkey]) {
                $newkey = count($newarray[$key]);
                $newarray[$key][$newkey] = $subvalue;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $newarray[$key] = $value;
    }
}

//Final result
print('<pre>'.print_r($newarray, true).'</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge_recursive` is not required since there is only 1 level for each ID and your `array_key_exists` will always be true since you are getting the same key from foreach and checking on the same array.

---

You can straightaway get values based on `id` (which is `77` etc in your case) and keep merging values. You can later `array_unique` them only once for efficiency and get only unique values for each id.

```
<?php

$result = [];

foreach($d as $subs){
    foreach($subs as $id => $values){
        $result[ $id ] = array_merge($result[ $id ] ?? [], $values);
    }
}

$result = array_map(fn($v) => array_unique($v), $result);

print_r($result);
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/HrXSA)

Comment: [`$result = array_map('array_unique', $result);`](https://3v4l.org/hQYl5)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
  foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
    $result[$key] = array_unique(array_merge($result[$key] ?? [], ...[ $values ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers miss the opportunity to educate and empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code

```
  <?php
    
    
    // Given arrays
    $array1 = [
        77 => ['Bold Condensed', 'Bold Condensed 2', 'Bold Condensed 3'],
    ];
    
    $array2 = [
        77 => ['Bold Condensed'],
        136 => ['Regular'],
    ];
    
    $array3 = [
        77 => ['Bold Condensed (1, 2, 3)'],
        168 => ['Regular', 'Bold'],
    ];
    
    // Function to merge arrays
    function mergeArrays(...$arrays)
    {
        $result = [];
    
        foreach ($arrays as $array) {
            foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
                if (!isset($result[$key])) {
                    $result[$key] = $values;
                } else {
                    // Merge values, removing duplicates
                    $result[$key] = array_values(array_unique(array_merge($result[$key], $values)));
                }
            }
        }
    
        return $result;
    }
    
    // Merge the arrays
    $mergedArray = mergeArrays($array1, $array2, $array3);
    
    // Output the merged array
    print_r($mergedArray);
    
    ?>
```

The mergeArrays function will accepts multiple arrays as arguments and merges them into a single result array. It loop through each array, combining values for each key while removing duplicates

Answer (score 0):

To avoid making evermore expensive `array_merge()` and `array_unique()` calls on every iteration of a nested loop, maintain a temporary lookup array and only push unique values into the result array.  In other words, don't make a mess for your code to clean up later.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AbD92))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arrays as $set) {
    foreach ($set as $id => $row) {
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            if (!isset($lookup[$id][$value])) {
                $lookup[$id][$value] = $value;
                $result[$id][] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  77 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Bold Condensed',
    1 => 'Bold Condensed 2',
    2 => 'Bold Condensed 3',
    3 => 'Bold Condensed (1, 2, 3)',
  ),
  136 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Regular',
  ),
  168 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Regular',
    1 => 'Bold',
  ),
)
```